# Phrase to trigger Action items in Office 365 (Outlook/OWA)

Tags: outlook-on-the-web, office-365

"Action items" in Office 365 Outlook detects sentence which needs follow up.

I am wondering what phrase besides "**please** ..." could be used to trigger this function?

Example:

[image: Action items]